# Set the icon of a Flex button with a Sprite in runtime

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, button, icons

I want to set the icon of a button in flex.

The default syntax is as follows.

```
myButton.setStyle("icon", iconClass);
```

and iconClass is normally an embedded object.

But what I want to do is, use a standard **Sprite or a MovieClip** (which I find during runtime) as the icon.

Is this possible? Has anyone done this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a possible solution. http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=42 Will give this ago and report.

Comment: Hi Chands, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a fatal flaw in Flex's framework in regards to styling. When Flex grabs a style value for an icon it assumes it's of type `Class` and that the instantiated object will be of type `DisplayObject` (or derived). It's a trivial change to the code (which classes like `mx:Image` do for their source property) to test whether or not the style's value is of type `DisplayObject` and if so, just skip the construction step that it currently performs.

Ben's solution is the best possible if you won't want to change the Flex framework source. Personally, I end up monkey-patching the specific components to accept instantiated `DisplayObjects` instead of `Classes.` Some components are more of a pain than others to patch.

[Doug McCune explaining how to monkey patch the Flex framework.](http://dougmccune.com/blog/2008/02/21/monkey-patching-flexsprite-to-list-all-event-listeners-on-any-flex-component/)